# conda activate failed in fish

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, fish

I am using conda 23.7.4 and fish shell on Windows10,I execute `conda init fish`successfully,but `conda activate pytorch` failed, and the error report said:

```
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [--no-plugins] [-V] COMMAND ...
conda-script.py: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate' (choose from 'clean', 'compare', 'config', 'create', 'info', 'init', 'install', 'list', 'notices', 'package', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'rename', 'run', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade', 'build', 'content-trust', 'convert', 'debug', 'develop', 'doctor', 'index', 'inspect', 'metapackage', 'render', 'skeleton', 'repo', 'pack', 'verify', 'server', 'token', 'env')
```

But I can run `conda activate pytorch` successfully in cmd. Why can't fish?

Comment: Did you restart fish after `conda init fish`? As far as I know that adds some lines to config.fish, so that needs to run again.